# UWP - Panel, last element auto height

Tags: c#, uwp, panel, stackpanel

in C# WPF we got a DockPanel, where we can easy use it to auto resize the last element. The StackPanel and the RelativePanel needs a height on the elements to works with... So how its works now in UWP without add something damn code in the .cs file from the view.

For the image: the green rectangle is fixed, like 50px or 100px, the height is controlled by the element himself. And the red rectangle fills the rest of the panel. So my window is 500px - the green is 50px and the red 450px. If I resize the window to 600 for an example - the green is still 50px and the red 550px

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `RelativePanel` so that we can understand what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Can you provide a diagram or some XAML with the DockPanel to explain what kind of layout you are trying to achieve? StackPanel and Grid are able to provide auto-sizing layouts.

Comment: Sorry, I add a screenshot with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Grid with * for the row height:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />       <!-- Take as much as needed -->
      <RowDefinition Height="20" />        <!-- Take exactly 20 DIP -->
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />        <!-- Take all the rest -->
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" /> 
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" /> 
  <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" /> 

</Grid>
```